# Can't adopt micro-sd card on Moto Z2 Force

Tags: sd-card, adoptable-storage

I have a new Moto Z2 Force, bought for the Qualcom Snapdragon 835 and the 6GB RAM, running Nougat 7.1.1. I also have a new Samsung 224GB U3 micro-SD card for it. That operates nicely as an exchangeable card.

I can't find a way to format the card as internal storage, or otherwise adopt it into the device's own storage. Searching for information about this, I'm finding a lot of postings on various forums that advise against adopting a card, because it often gives trouble.

Is adopting a large card as internal storage considered bad practice nowadays?

Comment: It's always been considered "bad practice"... It is just a crutch for phones with low storage space. SD cards fail, it happens, and when it does it's catastrophic when used as adopted storage. The write cycles done when it is adopted storage cause it fail, usually sooner than expected and without warning. If you don't absolutely need the "internal" storage space, don't do it.

Comment: Agree with @acejavelin. You can read more on the wiki and questions on it to understand why

Comment: I mean on the tag added to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moto [removed the adoptable storage feature from their devices](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-Z-Force/Does-it-matter-which-SD-card-to-use/m-p/3799832#M758). It's not bad practice; I definitely like it. As for bad practice, I think it's a good thing, but it definitely requires more mindful usage of your device, which a lot of folks aren't used to.

Answer (score 1):

Use a high endurance microSD card! Make routine backups, because everything has a risk of breaking. Statistically, there is a higher risk of gravitational accident [drop], aqueous accident [get wet], or velocity accident [vehicle crash] damaging your phone and causing loss of data, than the risk of a high endurance microSD card losing data.

Samsung has 2x higher endurance than SanDisk, circa 2019.

For ultra high reliability, use industrial grade SLC microSD card. It will outlast the consumer grade MLC/TLC/QLC flash circuits in your phone.